# How to match a user-input with a key in the hash table in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
guide_book = {"Delhi" => "011", "Noida" => "0120", "Indore" => "0731", "beas" => "458", "goa" => "835"}
```

I want to match the user input string `city_name` with the key in the hash table. If the input matches any key, then the code should be printed, else a note of invalid city should be printed.

This is the code I wrote:

```
puts "Please enter the city name"
city_name = gets.chomp
puts "Thank You"
puts "The available cities in the city guide are"
guide_book.each{|k,v| puts k}
```

Comment: So whats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
guide_book.default = "invalid city"
puts guide_book[city_name]
```

Comment: Excellent! I forget about `default` but this is a great use for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a hash contains a key by using [`has_key?`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F)

Something like:

```
guide_book.has_key?(city_name)
```

**Edit**: (Thanks to [Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan) for the suggestion)

You can use [`Hash#key?`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) method, as `Hash#has_key?` is deprecated (See [this](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/43765)).

Comment: `Hash#has_key?` is deprecated in favor of [`Hash#key?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) ([background](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/43765)).